# Injected CSS file not applied to injected markup ASP.NET 4

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hullo everyone, I am building a simple aspx webpage that looks a word up in a dictionary (get url with query string), injects the result in a placeholder and formats its contents appropriately by retrieving a css file from the dictionary website.

Apparently I can't figure out how to solve the third point, in fact I have tried multiple approaches but none seems to work.

To be precise, I have successfully retrieved a link to the right css file and injected it into page header (tried: Page_load, Page_Init event), the query result is injected in the 'resultpanel' place holder in the Button_click event handler.

I have also included my ASPX markup followed by the corresponding codebehind file
This project uses HtmlAgilityPack.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Multidictionary.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="hdr"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h3>
            Enter URL and get contents of the page</h3>
        <asp:textbox id="TextBoxURL" runat="server" height="20px" width="250px" text="http://www.vandale.nl/opzoeken?pattern=kat&lang=nn">
        </asp:textbox>
        <asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" text="Get Contents" onclick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
        <asp:literal runat="server" id="resultpanel"></asp:literal>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace Multidictionary
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private string dictionaryUrl = "http://www.vandale.nl";
        private IEnumerable<HtmlNode> csslink;

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //your code
            string url = TextBoxURL.Text;
            var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
            var document = webGet.Load(url);
            csslink = (from el in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//link[@type='text/css']")
                       where
                       (el.Attributes["rel"] != null) && ("stylesheet".Equals(el.Attributes["rel"].Value))
                       select el);
            if (csslink != null && csslink.Count() > 0)
            {
                HtmlLink cssLink = new HtmlLink();
                cssLink.Href = dictionaryUrl + csslink.FirstOrDefault().Attributes["href"].Value;//"path to CSS";
                cssLink.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
                cssLink.Attributes["media"] = "all";
                hdr.Controls.Add(cssLink);
            }
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = TextBoxURL.Text;
            var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
            var document = webGet.Load(url);
            var definitieDiv = from el in document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                               where (el.Attributes["id"] != null) && ("content-area".Equals(el.Attributes["id"].Value))
                               select el;
            if (definitieDiv != null && definitieDiv.Count() > 0)
            {
                resultpanel.Text = definitieDiv.FirstOrDefault().OuterHtml;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Should my question need any clarification please do not hesitate to contact me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the resulting html in your browser? I am expecting that the stylesheets are missing there domain part of the url.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, yes I have, apparently everything is correct:
<head><title>

</title><link href="http://www.vandale.nl/sites/default/files/css/css_f50d4c2c6666e759d4a7cd8dbf8d2a88.css" type="text/css" media="all"></head>
I suspect it has something to do with the order of the two injections. I have also checked I am retrieving the correct CSS file.

Comment: i miss the http keyword in front of the vandals.nl

Comment: I have checked with 'Show source'  and it is there. if it does not appear in my comments it is because it gets formatted as link by Stack overflow.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the resulting html? I can't think of what goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestions I have (apparently) solved it, the server-side code did not add the attribute rel="stylesheet" to the link and therefore Chrome refused to apply the injected styles.

Comment: Mention this in your comments and I will accept your answer. Hartelijk bedankt voor uw hulp!